# Vertically align product images with bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align the product images with the bottom in order to keep the prices aligned. So basically this is what it looks like right now :

[image: What it looks like now]

This is how I'd like it to look like :

[image: How it should look like]

I've tried with `vertical-align: bottom;` but that didn't work.

I am using Woocommerce and I was not able to find out anywhere.

This is the link of the website : [here](http://dllpresse.ca/)

Kind regards!

Comment: Wrap the image tag inside the list item within a div and give it a fixed height in CSS. It will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try table layout.

```
.featured-product-tabs .tab-content ul.products {
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
}

ul.products li.product.product-home {
  text-align: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: `display: table;` for ul, and `display: table-cell;  vertical-align: bottom;` for li.

Comment: Which browser are you checking?

Comment: Where should I add the float:none ? Thank you!

Comment: `ul.products li.product.product-home`

Comment: You truly are a genius! I guess I'd need to do something similar for the archive pages such as this one ? http://dllpresse.ca/categorie/logiciels/

Comment: @RobertMiller Mark the answer if it worked for you. Please open a new question if you have an extension to the current one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go about this. Here's a solution I would suggest.

**The main problem you have is that the images are of different sizes. Had the images been of the same size, there wouldn't be an issue. So, this is the problem that you need to tackle.**

Taking a look at the `CSS` in the `Inspect Element`, there are a couple of things I observe. First, there is a styling defined as such :

```
img, video, object {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

The `height` property here isn't needed. **Also, the fact that it has** `!important` **doesn't help our cause**. You can get rid of this property i.e. modify the class as such :

```
img, video, object {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**Next thing you need to target is to get all the images to be of the same size**. I see a class specifically targeting the images here :

```
ul.products li.product a img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 8px;
}
```

What you can do is add a fixed `height` along with a `max-height` property and a `max-width` property. The `max-width` and `max-height` property will prevent the images from scaling out of proportion while the `height` property will force all the images to be of the same `height` (select this value carefully). Just to give an example for the purpose of illustration, you can modify the class as follows :

```
ul.products li.product a img {
    width:100%;
    max-width: 10em;         /*added property*/
    height:15em;             /*added property*/
    max-height: 20em;        /*added property*/
    display:block;
    margin:0 0 8px;
}
```

I made these changes in the `Inspect Element` to arrive at this image :

[image]

**EDIT : The images are not centered because of two reasons. First, there is a** `float` **property applied to it as follows :**

```
.wp-post-image {
    float: left;
}
```

Remove this code.**Secondly, as you can see in the code above, the** `margin` **property is as follows :**

```
margin:0 0 8px;
```

Just change it to :

```
margin:0 auto 8px;
```

This will center the images. See the updated image below :

[image]

Comment: I truly appreciate your help! This is creating another issue though with the alignment of the title as they are no longer centered. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertMiller I have updated my answer. You can center your images by making changes as suggested in the edit section.

Answer (score 1):

just wrap image in a container <div> and css that div:

```
position:relative;
height:100px; you can change the height value here;
```

and css that image:

```
position: relative|absolute|fixed; choose one from this three;
bottom: 0;
```

like this image will alway at the bottom of the div.