# How to align product boxes to bottom in archive page of Woocommerce whilst keeping images uncropped?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the products displayed on archive pages of Woocommerce align at the bottom so that bigger images can be seen as bigger as smaller images in the same row.

I want this page

https://dewaldthuysamen.com/trophy/product-category/trophies/hockey-trophies/

To show products aligned to bottom like this page

http://trophyshoponline.co.za/hockey.html

Thanks,

I have already tried this as I thought it would work but maybe CSS identifiers need to change.

[Vertically align product images with bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491552/vertically-align-product-images-with-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function archieve_styles() {
    $custom_css = "
        .woocommerce ul.products{
            display: inline !important;
        }
        .woocommerce ul.products .product{
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            float: none;
        }
        body .oceanwp-row .span_1_of_5 {
            width: 19%;
        }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce-inline', $custom_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'archieve_styles', 999 );
```